# Jquery asynchronous issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, return-value, promise

I should use this function's **return value** for doing some controls. Even if res's value turn to false result of the "when-then" process, hasIllegalRoute function return, res is true. Because jquery works asynchronously so doesn't wait to finish when-then operation for return res's value. How can i solve this problem?

```
function hasIllegalRoute()
{
  var res = true;  
  $.when(returnUncompletedRoute()).then(function(routeList)
  { 
    if(routeList.length>0)
    {
      var uncompletedRoute = 0;
      var today = new Date();
      routeList.forEach(function(e)
      {
        var routeDate = new Date(e.ROUTE_DATE);  
        if(calcDay(routeDate) != calcDay(today))
        {
          uncompletedRoute++;
        } 
      });
      if(uncompletedRoute>0)
      {
        $("#errorPageRouteMenu").append("<p>Sonlandırılmamış kayıtlarınız var, bu kayıtları sonlandırmadan yeni bir rotaya başlayamazsınız</p>");  
        return false;
      }
    }    
    }).then(function(result)
    {
      res = result;
    });  
  return res;
}
```

Comment: `return false;` is it required in the first `.then()`

Comment: yes so result's value comes false and res=false

Comment: try changing this: `return false;` to this: `return res;` or remove it, as i know `return false;` stops the script execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with turning to function's type of callback;

```
function hasIllegalRoute(callback)
    {  
      var errorMsg;
      $.when(returnUncompletedRoute()).then(function(routeList)
      { 
        //filter query döndürdüğü için toList fonksiyonu ile promise'e çevirdik
        //query boş iken toList 0 uzunluğunda liste döndürdü onu kontrol ettik
        if(routeList.length > 0)
        {
          var uncompletedRoute = 0;
          var today = new Date();
          routeList.forEach(function(e)
          {
            var routeDate = new Date(e.ROUTE_DATE);  
            if(calcDay(routeDate) != calcDay(today))
            {
              uncompletedRoute++;
            } 
          });

          if(uncompletedRoute > 0)
          {
            errorMsg = ("<p>Sonlandırılmamış kayıtlarınız var, bu kayıtları sonlandırmadan yeni bir rotaya başlayamazsınız</p>");
          }

          return errorMsg;
        }    
      }).then(function(result)
      {
        if(typeof callback === "function")
        {
          callback(result);
        }
      });
    }  


    //Rotanın tarih kontrolü ve tamamlanmamış veya gönderilmemiş rota kontrolleri. Kontrol sonucunda, varsa hata mesajı döndürülür.
    function checkRouteDailyRecord(callback)
    { 
      var errorMsg;

      $.when(returnRouteDailyRecord()).then(function(e)
      {
        var transferStatus = e.TRANSFER_STATUS;
        var routeItem =  returnRouteDailyList(e.ROUTE_DAILY_ID) ;
        //Sorgudan kayıt dönmüyorsa hiç gün başlamamış demektir.Rotaya başlanabilir. 
        // return sonucunda result değeri undefined olur, hata mesajı gösterilmez ve checkRoute değeri false kalır 
        if(routeItem.length == 0)
          errorMsg = undefined ; 

        //Gönderilmiş ve gün sonu yapılmış rotaların sayısını hesaplama    
        if(transferStatus == 1 && routeItem.COMPLETED == 1)
          errorMsg = ("<p>Tüm verileriniz gönderilmiş olarak işaretlenmiş. Veri almadan rotaya başlayamazsınız</p>");

        if(transferStatus == 0 && routeItem.COMPLETED == 0)
        {
          today = new Date();
          var routeDate = new Date(routeItem.ROUTE_DATE);
          //Rota listesinden dönen rotaların tarihlerinin, bugün ile tek tek karşılaştırılması.
          //Eğer bugun harici bir rotanın rota sonu yapılmamışsa yeni rotaya başlanamaz.
          if(calcDay(today) != calcDay(routeDate))
          {
            errorMsg =('<p>' + routeDate + 'tarihine ait tamamlanmamış rotanız bulunmaktadır. Lütfen sistem yöneticinize danışınız.</p>');
          }
        }  
          // if(routeItem.COMPLETED == 1),
          // {
          //  read only 
          // }   
        return errorMsg;
      }).then(function(result)
      {
        if(typeof callback === "function")
        {
          callback(result);
        }
      }).fail(function()
      {
        if(typeof callback === "function")
        {
          callback(errorMsg);
        }
      });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can i solve this problem?

An asynchronous function [cannot have a `return` value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) (or at least none that depends on the future result). Instead, you will need to return the promise that you already have:

```
function hasIllegalRoute() {
  return $.when(returnUncompletedRoute()).then(function(routeList) {
//^^^^^^
    if(routeList.length>0) {
      var uncompletedRoute = 0;
      var today = new Date();
      routeList.forEach(function(e) {
        var routeDate = new Date(e.ROUTE_DATE);  
        if(calcDay(routeDate) != calcDay(today))
          uncompletedRoute++;
      });
      if(uncompletedRoute>0)
        $("#errorPageRouteMenu").append("<p>Sonlandırılmamış kayıtlarınız var, bu kayıtları sonlandırmadan yeni bir rotaya başlayamazsınız</p>");  
        return false;
    }
    return true;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
}
```

`hasIllegalRoute` does not return a boolean value now, but a Promise for that boolean value. For your controls, add a callback on that returned promise.

Btw, you might use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (which returns the expected boolean right away) instead of that complicated `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make this work with a `return` value from `hasIllegalRoute`. You need to perform any action that relies on the result of the `when/then` inside of its callback or some other function that it executes.

In other words:

```
if (uncompletedRoute > 0) {
      $("#errorPageRouteMenu").append("<p>Sonlandırılmamış kayıtlarınız var</p>");  
      // do not return here; instead, perform whatever action should happen 
      // when this would have done so
      // return false;
}
```

The best way to do this is to add a `callback` parameter to `hasIllegalRoute` that takes a function that's executed when the asynchronous processing is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the the last then setting res, pass in a callback function to hasIllegalRoute and call it with the result. Then you will have your result return asynchronously to the callback function, and there is no need for a return.

This may involve changing the structure of your use of hasIllegalRoute, but this is common asynchronous structure.

Sorry formatting on my mobile